# When using cURL to paste in information to text fields on a website and "pressing" enter, how can I verify it actually went through?

Tags: curl

I currently have a website that has two text input entires and an "Enter" button. I would like to automate the pasting of a first and last name and pressing Enter by the following:

```
curl -d "entry1=mark&entry2=jacobs&submitButton=Enter" http://URL/example.cgi
```

However, the above doesn't tell me if any error messages were returned after pasting in the first and last name into the form. Also, I am not sure if the "Enter" button was hit. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the http response status code. you can get it a few ways, take a look at this post it should help you out:

https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code

I'd start with pvandenberk's answer and do something like:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://www.example.org/
```

Comment: ideally, yes, but lots of web devs are lazy/incompetent and always send http 200, no matter what actually happened

Comment: @hanshenrik agreed, but from the sound of it this is OP's site. if he/she is sending useful responses this should work fine. if not, then they should start by doing so

Answer (score 1):

generally i'd wrap it in a script that parses it, eg

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$html=shell_exec('curl -d "entry1=mark&entry2=jacobs&submitButton=Enter" http://URL/example.cgi');
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
if(($ele=$domd->getElementById("error-div"))){
   echo "error: ".$ele->textContent;
}else{
  echo "success!";
}
```

(this example parses a page that has a `<div id="error-div">error-description</div>` when an error occurs.)

and then just run it like

```
$ ./myscript.php
```

instead of your curl invocation